# Present UINavigationBar + toolbar modally from UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios

I am creating a reader app and have the kindle app as an 
inspiration.

From the reader view (uiscrollview) I wish to present/animate a navigation bar 
and toolbar on a tap. Now the app (uiwindow) already has as its root view controller
a navigationVC, which is used for the flow for selecting book category and a book. I then make the top bar invisible when displaying the actual text in my uiscrollview.

I want to display that navigationVC again on a tap, is that possible? I tried in my uiscrollview bind a tapgesturerecognizer to present that controller modally but it didn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It works now, it wasn't as advanced as I thought. Actually, I had an error in my gesturerecognizer handler, which didn't set the `UINavigationController`'s properties :).